# I am trying to get a JavaScript Program to Print a letter grade and Percentage based on a average using a switch statement but the answer comes up NaN

Tags: javascript, average, counter, do-while, subtotal

In my program I am using a do-while loop to prompt for grades until a -1 is entered and then increments the amount of grades inputted. A while loop then checks if the grade isNaN or less then 0 or greater then 100. The program will ask for another grade if so. If a -1 is entered the program will break from the loop and calculate the average based on the counter for the grades and the total number of grades added together. When I run the program and put in a negative 1 to stop it prints the -1 inside of the table and the semester average displays as NaN. I am assuming this is because the negative -1 makes it not a non positive number but I am unsure how to fix this.

Here is my code.

```
do { 
grade = prompt('Enter grade(-1 to stop)');
count++; 
while (grade < -1 || grade > 100  || isNaN(grade)) {
grade = prompt('Enter grade again (-1 to stop)');
} 
document.write('<td>Grade ' + count  +  '</td>');
document.write('<td width="50"> ' + grade + ' </td>');
document.write('</tr>');


}
 
while (grade != -1) {
    --total;
    alert("You have input -1 to stop");
document.write('</table>');     
 }
total = total + grade; 
avg = total / count;
document.write('Semester Average: ' + avg + '<br /><br />');
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix your problem here

https://jsfiddle.net/51v3qft9/26/

This is the snippet which may not be correct as your logic but it works for me

```
  var count = 0
  var total = 0
  var avg = 0

  document.write('<table>');

  do {
    grade = prompt('Enter grade(-1 to stop)');

        //if user key-in nothing, we need to ask user to key-in again
    while (!grade || grade < -1 || grade > 100 || isNaN(grade)) {
      grade = prompt('Enter grade again (-1 to stop)');
    }

        //whenever user key-in -1, we need to break `while`
    if (grade == -1) {
      break
    }

    count++;

    document.write('<td>Grade ' + count + '</td>');
    document.write('<td width="50"> ' + grade + ' </td>');
    document.write('</tr>');

    total += Number(grade); // you need to convert `grade` to number

  } while (grade != -1)

  alert("You have input -1 to stop");
  document.write('</table>');

  if(count > 0) {
    avg = total / count;
  }
  
  document.write('Semester Average: ' + avg + '<br /><br />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

https://jsfiddle.net/sean7777/qtf3v4rn/26/

`Hope this helps :)`